# How to select Arrow keys command in shell script to automate a deployment process?

Tags: bash, automation, netlify

I am trying to automate the deployment process in Netlify using a Shell script, I do get prompted with certain choices during the process. How can I select arrow keys choices using shell command for the same ??

[image: Shell Script Deployment]

Comment: Take a look at https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect